# PHP css only links when php filename is specified

Tags: php, html, css, include

I've been working on a php site for a while now with no issues, but I just noticed a problem. When I type in the address of my website while specifying the filename (i.e. localhost:4000/website/index.php), the page loads properly.

However, when I type in the address of my website *without* specifying the filename (i.e. localhost:4000/website), the html portion of the page loads, but the CSS page does not.

I have my CSS link in a php include page. This is the line of code that loads the CSS page.

```
<link href = "styles\main.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" />
```

The php files are in the main folder, called "website", the stylesheet is in "website/styles", and the included php file that contains the link tag is in "website/lib".

I have also tried changing the link tag to the following:

```
<link href = "..\styles\main.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" />
```

however, when the link tag is changed to this, the CSS doesn't load at all (whether or not filename is specified).

Does anyone have any idea as to why the stylesheet loads when the filename is specified, but not otherwise?

Comment: Look up how html relative paths work.

Comment: @John I'm well aware of how relative paths work. The problem is that, when the filename is not specified, the path no longer works. It's the exact same page being loaded (index.php) however, the path, for some reason, stops working if index.php is not specified. When index.php IS specified, the path works. The path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try it. I hope work.

```
<link href = "styles/main.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" />
```

use / instead of \

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. Oddly enough, I had to specify "styles/main.css" AND "website/styles/main.css". Whether / or \ doesn't have an effect though.